# MVC Script Section

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to add two script to my cshtml page.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

But my Jquery functions wasnt working.
Also tought putting my `<script>` tag at the end would solve the issue, but didnt.

After a while testing I realize I have to put the script inside a Script Section

```
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
}
```

I tought @section Scripts was to avoid repeat code along the different pages, but dont understand why my `<script>` tag doesnt work outside the @section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  tags do work outside the Scripts section. It's all about timing of when the jQuery script loads, versus when you're javascript that uses jQuery is run. Basically, the  that includes jQuery needs to be included in the page before the code that calls jQuery is run.

If you look at the rendered HTML that's sent to the browser, you'll see this difference between the two methods. Also, the browser debug tools will show you errors indicating this that "$" is undefined or similary.